# typescript load json data from url into arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

I have json data coming in from a URL. The data looks like this:

```
[
  {"id":1,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1927-12-30T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.66,"high":17.66,"low":17.66,"close":17.66,"volume":0},
  {"id":2,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1928-01-03T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.76,"high":17.76,"low":17.76,"close":17.76,"volume":0}
]
```

The code to retrieve it is in *quote.service.ts* and looks like this:

```
  getQuotesList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
```

Here is the whole class:

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
        import { of } from 'rxjs';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
        import 'rxjs/operator/filter';
        import { Quote } from "./quote";
        
        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class QuoteService {
        
          private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes';
        
          constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
        
          getQuote(id: number): Observable<any> {
            return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
          }
        
          createQuote(quote: Object): Observable<Object> {
            return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, quote);
          }
        
          updateQuote(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {
            return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, value);
          }
        
          deleteQuote(id: number): Observable<any> {
            return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
          }
        
          //getQuotesList(): Observable<any> {
          //  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
          //}
    
    getQuotesList(): Observable<[string[], string[]]> {
      // replace of(data) to this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
      return of(data).pipe(
        map((quotes) => {
          return quotes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            acc[0].push(curr.date.substr(0, 10));
            acc[1].push(curr.open);
            return acc;
          }, [[], []]);
        }),
      )
    }
}
```

The data is then sent on to *quote-list.component.ts* which successfully loads it into the quotes array like this:

```
export class QuoteListComponent implements OnInit {
  quotes: Observable<Quote[]>;
```

It then passes `quotes` on to *quote-list.component.html* and builds a table using the following code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let quote of quotes | async">
  <td>{{quote.symbol}}</td>
  <td>{{quote.date}}</td>
  <td>{{quote.open}}</td>
  <td>{{quote.high}}</td>
  <td>{{quote.low}}</td>
  <td>{{quote.close}}</td>
  <td>{{quote.volume}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="deleteQuote(quote.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      <button (click)="quoteDetails(quote.id)" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px">Details</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The table looks nice and all the data is there.

Now I want to load it into a separate array for each value, like this:

```
[1927-12-30,1928-01-03]
[17.66,17.76]
```

etc.

And then I want to make those arrays available to a javascript charting program which will plot the data.  That plotting code requires a separate array for each value.

I thought that if I modified *quote.service.ts* to look something like

```
  getQuotesList(): Observable<any> {
    let quotes = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
    let opens = quotes.map(theOpen => open);
    console.log("opens.length=" + opens.length);
    opens.forEach(function(item,index,array) {
        console.log(item,index);
        })
    return quotes;
  }
```

But get the error:

> ```
> ERROR in quote.service.ts:38:23 - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
>
> 38    let opens = quotes.map(theOpen => open);
> ```

So I changed `getQuotesList(): Observable<any>` to `getQuotesList(): Observable<Quote[]>`

But got the following error:

> ```
> ERROR in quote.service.ts:38:23 - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
>
> 38    let opens = quotes.map(theOpen => open);
>                          ~~~
> quote.service.ts:43:4 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Quote[]>'.
>   The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
>     Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Quote[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
> ```

So I changed `let opens = quotes.map(theOpen => open);` to `let opens = quotes.pipe(map(theOpen => open));`

But got the error

```
ERROR in quote.service.ts:39:40 - error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Observable<(url?: string, target?: string, features?: string, replace?: boolean) => Window>'.

39    console.log("opens.length=" + opens.length);
                                          ~~~~~~
quote.service.ts:40:18 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(item: any, index: any, array: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: (url?: string, target?: string, features?: string, replace?: boolean) => Window) => void'.

40    opens.forEach(function(item,index,array) {
```

Then I tried:

```
getQuotesList() {
  let quotes = this.http.get<Quote[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  let opens = quotes.pipe(map(theOpen => open));
  alert(opens[0]);
  return quotes;
}
```

But the output was "undefined"

Then I tried

```
private quoteObserver = {
  next(quote) {
    console.log("quote.open=" +quote.open);
  }
}

getQuotesList() {
  let quotes = this.http.get<Quote[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  of(quotes).subscribe(this.quoteObserver);
  return quotes;
}
```

but the output was `quote.open=undefined`

Then I tried

```
  getQuotesList(): Observable<any> {
    let quotes = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
    quotes.subscribe(arr => {
      Object.values(arr[0].forEach(el => {
        let col = arr.map(ele => ele[el]);
        console.log(el,':', col);
      }
    )}
    return quotes;
  }
```

But the error was

```
ERROR in quote.service.ts:67:6 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

67     )}
        ~
quote.service.ts:68:5 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

68     return quotes;
       ~~~~~~


    ERROR in quote.service.ts:64:23 - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

    64         let col = arr.map(ele => ele[el]);
```

Do you think I've made enough attempts yet? :-(
I'm new to Angular/Typescript so hoping someone can guide me.

EDIT: I managed to figure how to port the code over to a linux server. Now you can access the back end to see the actual data coming in by entering this in the browser: 167.172.141.34:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes

Comment: As I understand you want each object of the quotes array to be an array with only the values from that specific object?

Comment: Each field of the quotes array, like date, open, high, low, close would each be in a separate array.

Comment: Please add an stackblitz sample so everyone can give an straight answer. BTW. The answer to your question is YES, you did enough tries.  Also the last error `quote.service.ts:68:5 - error TS1005: ',' expected` is **JUST A TYPO!!** the subscribe closing bracket looks like this `)}` and it should be `})`

Comment: I'll try to figure out stackblitz (yet another thing).  Thanks for finding the typo.  Now there are 3 errors.  Here is the first one: ERROR in quote.service.ts:69:5 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

69     })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pieces to this question. One is how to convert the JSON data to the array format that you want, and the other issue is how to work with `Observables` which wrap the actual data you're trying to access.

For the first piece, here is sample code which should convert the data format:

```js
const quotes = [
  {"id":1,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1927-12-30T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.66,"high":17.66,"low":17.66,"close":17.66,"volume":0},
  {"id":2,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1928-01-03T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.76,"high":17.76,"low":17.76,"close":17.76,"volume":0}
] 

const chartData = Object.assign({}, 
  ...Object.keys(quotes[0]).map(key => ({
    [key]: quotes.map(quote => quote[key])
  })))

console.log(chartData)
```

And to get the data out of the observable you just subscribe to it. I've included the conversion code from above as a separate function but you could inline it as well:

```
getQuotesList() {
  const quotes = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
  quotes.subscribe(quotes => this.toChart(quotes))
  return quotes
}

toChart (quotes) {
  const chartData = Object.assign({}, 
      ...Object.keys(quotes[0]).map(key => ({
          [key]: quotes.map(quote => quote[key])
      })))
  console.log(chartData)
}
```

Comment: When I run your code snippet, it works nicely.  When I paste it into my code, I get 3 errors.  Here is the first one: ERROR in quote.service.ts:167:1 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

167 function toChart (quotes) {
    ~~~~~~~~
quote.service.ts:175:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

175 }

Comment: If I remove the "function" keyword (since it is within a class) and change "toChart" to "this.toChart" then I get 2 errors.  Here is the first one: ERROR in quote.service.ts:168:28 - error TS2339: Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

    168   const chartData = Object.fromEntries(

Comment: @user3217883 that error means you're targeting an older javascript version. I've updated the code to something that should work on that version, give it a try again.

Comment: I pasted your new code and that got it down to only 1 error: ERROR in quote-list/quote-list.component.ts:24:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Quote[]>'.
      The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
        Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Quote[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

    24     this.quotes = this.quoteService.getQuotesList();  I changed getQuotesList() to getQuotesList<any> and then it worked!  Finally!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapping

```js
var arr=[
  {"id":1,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1927-12-30T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.66,"high":17.66,"low":17.66,"close":17.66,"volume":0},
  {"id":2,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1928-01-03T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.76,"high":17.76,"low":17.76,"close":17.76,"volume":0}
]



Object.keys(arr[0]).forEach(el=>{
  let arrray= (el=="date") ? arr.map(ele=> ele[el].substring(0,10)) : arr.map(ele=>ele[el]);
  console.log(el,':', arrray);
  // use your logic here
})
```

use subscrribe

```
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`).subscribe(arr=>{
   Object.keys(arr[0]).forEach(el=>{
      let arrray= (el=="date") ? arr.map(ele=> ele[el].substring(0,10)) : 
      arr.map(ele=>ele[el]);
      console.log(el,':', arrray);
      // use your logic here
   })
});
```

Comment: Does this create a single array?  Anyway, I got the following errors after compile:     ERROR in quote.service.ts:33:36 - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

    33          let arrray= (el=="date") ? arr.map(ele=> ele[el].substring(0,10)) : arr.map(ele=>ele[el]);
                                               ~~~
    quote.service.ts:33:77 - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

    33          let arrray= (el=="date") ? arr.map(ele=> ele[el].substring(0,10)) : arr.map(ele=>ele[el]);

Comment: to use map function you need array so you need to subscribe your observable result.

Comment: Thankyou for the runnable code snippet.  I'd like to learn how to do that some day.  Clearly it works as I want, but the issue, it appears, is that of the Observable<any> not being able to map.  Even my solution, above, shows that the "opens" array has a length of undefined.  I've tried all kinds things to overcome but no luck yet.  I will rewrite the post to include things I've tried.

Comment: When I use your subscribe method, I get the following error: ERROR in quote.service.ts:57:3 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

57   return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`).subscribe(arr=>{

Comment: Also, could you please explain what is happening with your runnable code snippet?  I'm pretty new to angular/typescript and the syntax is hard to grasp.  I can see how it gets each element in a row but don't see how it gets each row.

Answer (score 0):

The subscribe approach is correct, but you are not handing the resulting array in the right way. Insided the subscribe callback you get an actual array, so you can use your original `.map` approach that was not working on the observer object in your attempt #1

```js
getQuotesList(): Observable<any> {
  let quotes = this.http.get<Quote[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  quotes.subscribe((arr: Quote[]) => {
    const opens = arr.map(quote => quote.open)
    console.log(opens); // [17.66,17.76]

    const dates = arr.map(quote => quote.date.split("T")[0])
    console.log(dates); // [1927-12-30,1928-01-03]
  )}
  return quotes;
}
```

Comment: I pasted in your code and here is the first of 4 errors I got: ERROR in quote.service.ts:136:3 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

136   )}.  I was reading up on this and now I think it is wrong to have a separate "let quotes = ..." because of the async nature, quotes.subscribe will start running before all the quotes have even arrived.

Answer (score 0):

This code smells a lot...
I think that the QuoteService method named "getQuotesList"should only have one purpose: return an Observable<Quote[]> as you did in the beginning.

What I think you need to do in your component is to store the quote observable, and create a new observable with a switchMap operator (with reduce logic inside).

you should check this stackblitz for possible solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uurnuv?file=index.ts

Cheers!

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to test a solution.  The problem is that you hard-code the data: const getQuotesList = of([
  {"id":1,"symbol":"SP-500",...  I need the data to come from the url.  @pc_coder's solution also works with hard-coded data.

Comment: of course i hardcoded data because i have no access to your API...
In my example getQuotesList is a stub which returns an  Observable<Quote[]>, which is the same as doing a http request with your service /method myService.getQuoteList() that will returns an Observable<Quote[]> as well...

Comment: Yea, I get you don't have much choice.  I will get everything copied and working on a remote server where you will have access to the backend call.

Comment: I managed to figure how to port the code over to a linux server. Now you can access the back end to see the actual data coming in by entering this in the browser: 167.172.141.34:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes

Comment: Unfortunatly the server is down (connexion refused). 


I improved a bit my example with comments. Tell me if you have questions. 

See : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ykfuie?file=index.ts
Cheers!

Comment: In my example you have 1 observable of getQuotesList subscribed twice. 
1 for raw quotes data
1 for chart data

Answer (score 0):

You have error in `getQuotesList()`.

```
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const data = [
  {"id":1,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1927-12-30T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.66,"high":17.66,"low":17.66,"close":17.66,"volume":0},
  {"id":2,"symbol":"SP-500","date":"1928-01-03T07:00:00.000+00:00","open":17.76,"high":17.76,"low":17.76,"close":17.76,"volume":0}
];

function getQuotesList(): Observable<[string[], string[]]> {
  // replace of(data) to this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
  return of(data).pipe(
    map((quotes) => {
      return quotes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc[0].push(curr.date.substr(0, 10));
        acc[1].push(curr.open);
        return acc;
      }, [[], []]);
    }),
  )
}

getQuotesList().subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-j8ptal?file=index.ts

#### UPDATE:

It is full class of your service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, Subject, of } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/operator/filter";
import { Quote } from "./quote";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class QuoteService {
  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getQuote(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  createQuote(quote: Object): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, quote);
  }

  updateQuote(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, value);
  }

  deleteQuote(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: "text" });
  }

  //getQuotesList(): Observable<any> {
  //  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  //}

  getQuotesList(): Observable<[string[], string[]]> {
    // replace of(data) to this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
    return this.http.get<Quote[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      map(quotes => {
        return quotes.reduce(
          (acc, curr) => {
            acc[0].push(curr.date.substr(0, 10));
            acc[1].push(curr.open);
            return acc;
          },
          [[], []]
        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I pasted your code into quote.service.ts and here is the first of 4 errors I got: ERROR in quote.service.ts:141:1 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

141 function getQuotesList(): Observable<[string[], string[]]> {
    ~~~~~~~~
quote.service.ts:155:3 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

155   }

Comment: I also did replace of(data) to this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`) (${this.baseUrl} is within single quotes that don't show up in this box.

Comment: Can you show your full class? May be you forgot remove `function` keyword, which is not needed in class.

Comment: Ok, I added the full class in the post

Comment: See my update. The complete class is written in it.

Comment: I pasted your code in got 2 errors.  Here is the first one:

    ERROR in quote.service.ts:148:35 - error TS2339: Property 'substr' does not exist on type 'Date'.

    148             acc[0].push(curr.date.substr(0, 10));

Comment: I managed to figure how to port the code over to a linux server.  Now you can access the back end to see the actual data coming in by entering this in the browser: http://167.172.141.34:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes

Comment: In HTTP response result there can be no `Date`. You receive JSON, which must contain only scalar types (`string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `array` or `object`). There is no way you can get `Date` in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand what you want.

1. You want to parse json data to data(typed Object all something)
2. You want to aggregate data toArrayValues.

Right?

I make some code for you.

```ts
interface Quote {
  id: number;
  symbol: string;
  date: string;
  open: number;
  high: number;
  low: number;
  close: number;
  volume: number;
}

const jsonList = [{
    "id": 1,
    "symbol": "SP-500",
    "date": "1927-12-30T07:00:00.000+00:00",
    "open": 17.66,
    "high": 17.66,
    "low": 17.66,
    "close": 17.66,
    "volume": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "symbol": "SP-600",
    "date": "1928-01-03T07:00:00.000+00:00",
    "open": 17.76,
    "high": 17.76,
    "low": 17.76,
    "close": 17.76,
    "volume": 0
  }
]


function jsonParse < T = any > (json: any): T | null {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('ERROR')
    return null;
  }
}

function aggregate < T = any > (dataList: T[]) {
  const aggregation = dataList.reduce < T[keyof T][][] > ((acc, data) => {
    Object.values(data).forEach((value: T[keyof T], index: number) => {
      if (Array.isArray(acc[index])) {
        acc[index].push(value);
        return acc;
      }
      acc[index] = [value]
      return acc;
    })
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return aggregation;
}

const quotes = jsonParse < Quote[] > (jsonList);
if (quotes) {
  const aggregationQuotes = aggregate < Quote > (quotes);
  console.log('quotes', quotes)
  console.log('aggregationQuotes', aggregationQuotes)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I finally got it to compile without error by first running this:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

And then adding this import:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And then adding the following code to get one array of "open" values:

```
  getQuotesList(): Observable<any> {
    let quotes = this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
    let opens = quotes.pipe(map(theOpen => open));
    console.log(opens);
    return quotes;
  }
```

Unfortunately, nothing is output by console.log(opens), but that is another problem.

Comment: To solve the console.log problem, go to node-modules>karma>lib>config.js and change browserConsoleLogOptions to 'log' from 'debug'

Comment: Installing compat is not a solution. Compat will not be supported with the next version of rxjs